# reference with const access

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Using pointers, I can create all combinations of (const/non_const) to (T / const T) for any type T, as discussed in detail [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/8769985).

But using references, how can I define a reference to a variable which can be dereferences (like an iterator), such that the dereferenced reference gives a const access?

For example, consider this program:

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a{0, 0, 0};
    auto const& iter = a.begin();
    // iter++; // Error!
    (*iter)++;
}
```

`iter` is `const` variable, and if you uncomment the line `iter++` the code cannot compile.
But `iter` dereferences to a non-const int, which in fact can be incremented with `(*iter)++`. In a sense, `iter` mimics `int * const`, i.e., a const pointer to int.

Is it possible to instead have a (const or non_const) reference `iter`, such that `*iter` is a const int?

Please bear in mind that I am aware that I could use `const auto& iter = a.cbegin()` in the example above. The purpose of the question is how to define `iter`, such that, when dereferenced, give a const access, irrespective of what is on the right of the equal operator.
For iterators I can imagine to explicitly bind to a `const_iterator`, like:

```
const decltype(a)::const_iterator& iter = a.begin();
```

This solution works because I know that the equivalent "const-access" of an `iterator` is a `const_iterator`.

But, more generally:

```
(some type)& iter = rhs
```

If all I know is that `*rhs` is a int, is it possible to find out the type of iter, such that `*iter` is a const int?

Another point worth to consider is the possible cost of the conversion of `rhs`.

Comment: Technically, you can't have a *"const reference"* in c++. You can have *"reference to const type"* though.

Comment: `auto iter = a.cbegin()` - `iter` is now a `const_iterator` - not a `const iterator&`

Comment: references do already refer to the actual object, you don't "dereference them".

Comment: Do you want `iter` to be `const` as well so it mimics a `const T * const`?

Comment: The definition of `iter`  will never change the meaning of your rhs.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sure, the sentence was not accurate-- I amended the text.

Comment: @NathanOliver the reference itself could also be const, when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to instead have a (`const` or non-`const`) reference `iter`, such that `*iter` is a `const int`?

You call the `std::array::cbegin()` member function that will return a `std::array<int, 3>::const_iterator`. Dereferencing that will give you a `const int&`.

- You can however *not* take the `const_iterator` by a non-`const` reference. You must take it by value or by `const&` (to prolong the life of the temporary returned by the `cbegin()` function). The general recommendation is to take iterators *by value* though.

> is it possible to find out the type of `iter`, such that `*iter` is a `const int`?

If you *know* that `iter` is some kind of pointer (`const T*`, `const T*&`, `T*` or `T*&` etc.) then you could get a `const T*` like this:

```cpp
const std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(iter)> constiter = iter;
```

For the general case, getting a `const_iterator` from an `iterator` without using the container's `typedef` for `const_iterator`, will be a bit cumbersome. One way could be to wrap the iterator in an interator class that only returns `const&`s when dereferenced.
Here's an example with a `std::list<int>::iterator` which is a little more complicated than a pointer. It works for pointers too though.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<class It>
struct const_iterator {
    using IterType = std::remove_reference_t<It>;
    using Traits = std::iterator_traits<IterType>;   

    using difference_type = typename Traits::difference_type;
    using value_type = const typename Traits::value_type;
    //                 ^^^^^
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using iterator_category = typename Traits::iterator_category;

    const_iterator(It nc) : value(nc) {}
    
    // dereferencing gives a const&
    reference operator*() const { return *value; }

    bool operator==(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return value == rhs.value; }
    bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
    
    const_iterator& operator++() { ++value; return *this; }
    const_iterator operator++(int) { const_iterator rv(*this); ++value; return rv; }

    // Add conditional support for proxy member functions supported
    // by the original iterator type / iterator_category

    IterType value;
};

template<class It>
const_iterator(It) -> const_iterator<It>;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> a{1, 2, 3};
    auto iter = a.begin();
    *iter = 10;                // Ok

    const_iterator cit(iter);  // make a const_iterator from the original iterator
    ++cit;                     // Ok
    std::cout << *cit << '\n'; // prints 2
    //*cit = 20;               // Error: *cit is a `const int&`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of the question is how to define `iter`, such that, when dereferenced, give a const access

And this is where const iterators come into play. For iterators it's actually a less global question, because a const iterator merely means a standard iterator to a constant container:

```cpp
const std::array<int, 3> a{ 0, 0, 0 };
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<decltype(a.begin()), decltype(a.cbegin())>,
    "The iterators are of different type"
);
```

Constness of the iterators' own types in this case doesn't actually depend on whether they point to a const type or not. As you already noticed, `const` iterator instead means that the iterator itself cannot be changed and point to a different object.

Answering your second question:

> Is it possible to instead have a (const or non_const) reference to const int?

No, a reference is always `const` implicitly and cannot be rebound after being bound to a variable.

Comment: Regarding the second question/answer, it's better to think of a reference as an *alias* which just an alternative identifier to the same object, rather than thinking of as being a bound "thing" that cannot be rebound.  The compiler may implement either approach under the covers, but that's not programmatically exposed.